# WCF Data Services updating entity error and type of table's primary key

Tags: sql-server, wcf, entity-framework, wcf-data-services

For some time I couldn't find out the cause of an error when trying to update a field in a table using WCF Data Services plus Entity Framework:

```
MydbEntities context = new MydbEntities(new Uri("http://localhost:53051/Services/MydbService.svc"));
MyEntity entitytoedit = context.MyEntity.FirstOrDefault();
entitytoedit.Name = "TheNewName";
context.UpdateObject(entitytoedit);
context.BeginSaveChanges(OnChangesSaved, context);
...
```

The error was like following: ***RequestException An error occurred while processing this request.***

The fix was to add an autoincremental `decimal(18, 0)` field as the Primary Key with Identity Specification `IsIdentity = yes` instead of just a `varchar(20)` field as the Primary Key.

Please, could anybody explain the nature of the problem: should I always use autoincremental Primary Keys with WCF Data Services? If not, where in fact am I wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that object was updated and not inserted again?

Comment: Pretty sure. At least, autoincremental Primary Key field value remained the same as before updating.

Comment: Did you try to turning on exception details? You can mark your service class with `[ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailsInFaults=true)]` or use this setting in configuration.

Comment: I tried to mark the class but didn't get much more info than before. Additional details about the error are that it's `Bad request` with code `400`

Comment: I tend to use Guids as primary keys, and not let the DB create them, but create them myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is more Entity Framework question than WCF Data Services.

You can either have primary key field that you set by hands and you must set `StoreGeneratedPattern` to `None`.

Or you can use `AutoIncrement` field as primary key and in this case you must set `StoreGeneratedPattern` for it to `Identity`.

Mixing this to cases always break the things. In addition when you do Model First, primary key field by default has type `int` and `StoreGeneratedPattern` set to `Identity`, so just changing the type to `decimal` as in your case is not enough.